# SQL Server Stored Procedure : Dynamic database in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a variable which holds the database that I am working on. How can I add this variable in a static query?

This is what I want to achieve:

```
if exists(select * from @DestinationDB.[RaPa] where tid = @dyid)
begin
    RAISERROR('Rapa exist',16,1)
end
```

Comment: Without Dynamic SQL, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you meant *without* Dynamic SQL... but here is how you *can* accomplish this *with* dynamic SQL

```
declare @DestinationDB varchar(64)
declare @dyid int
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @DestinationDB = 'SomeDB'
set @dyid = 14

set @sql = 
'if exists(select * from ' + quotename(@DestinationDB) + '.[RaPa] where tid = ' + cast(@dyid as varchar(16)) + ')
begin
    RAISERROR(''Rapa exist'',16,1)
end'

print @sql
--exec(@sql)
```

Just uncomment the exec part when you are satisfied with the command.